# ¿ Como asignar mi recompensa?

Tags: discusión, recompensas

Hace tiempo, un usuario nuevo publico una pregunta. La verdad es que no había por donde cogerla, y, tras algunos comentarios, el OP la borró.

De lo poco que *pillé* (entendí), formulé mi propia pregunta; la verdad es que el tema de los algoritmos me *chifla* (encanta), y no pude resistirme. Es ésta:

[¿Como reutilizo espacios en una tabla hash, despreciando los mas antiguos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/80201/23371)

Recientemente, puesto que solo había **1** respuesta, decidí ofrecer una recompensa, para llamar la atención.

Ahora, la respuesta inicial ha sido editada; solo por el trabajo invertido, entre la publicación inicial y esta última edición, ya se merece el *bonus*. Y es una **excelente** respuesta.

Además, de momento ha aparecido **otra** respuesta mas. Menos extensa, pero no por ello de menos calidad (a mi juicio, sin ser experto en el tema).

Por supuesto, **no descarto** la aparición de nuevas respestas; para ello fué que ofrecí la recompensa :-)

Puesto que la pregunta es poco menos que *retórica*, sin un problema real que solucionar, no me puedo basar en aquello de `ésta respuesta me sirvió`.

Así pues, me hallo en la tesitura:

¿ Como asigno la recompensa ?

<sub>**Nota:** Cierto, debí de pensarlo antes :O</sub>

Comment: "pille"? "chifla"? puedes hablar en Español? gracias!

Comment: Pues es español coloquial, pero es español

Answer (score 3):

Mi respuesta es para aclarar la diferencia entre **Aceptar una respuesta** y **Otorgar una recompensa**, que son dos cosas totalmente diferentes.

En cuanto a **Aceptar Respuestas**, en el articulo [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) dice:

> La aceptación de una respuesta no está destinada a ser una declaración
>   definitiva y última que indica que la pregunta ya ha sido contestada
>   perfectamente. Simplemente significa que el autor recibió una
>   respuesta que funcionó para él o ella en lo particular...

Tambien, en el articulo [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) dice:

> Escoge una respuesta que pienses que tenga la mejor solución a tu
>   problema.

Es decir, si la pregunta está dentro de la temática del sitio y si la respuesta funciona y es la mejor solución para el problema, entonces esta bien, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Ahora bien, en cuanto a **Otorgar Recompensas**, me gusta mucho lo que dice el Centro de Ayuda en el articulo [¿Qué es una recompensa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> El período de duración de una recompensa es de 7 días. Las
>   recompensas deben tener una duración mínima de al menos 1 día. Una
>   vez que la recompensa ha finalizado, hay un período de gracia de 24
>   horas para otorgarla manualmente. **Simplemente haz clic en el botón de
>   otorgar recompensa** que hay junto a cada respuesta para otorgarla
>   permanentemente al autor de la misma (énfasis mio)

Asi que, creo que *simplemente* tienes que darle la recompensa a la pregunta que más te ha gustado. Al final es tu recompensa y la recompensa no indica si la pregunta es la que más ayudo a tu pregunta, sino simplemente la que te gusto más.

Comment: Yo añadiría que puedes ofrecer una recompensa a una pregunta de otro, lo que deja más claro aún que **respuesta aceptada** y **recompensa** son dos cosas totalmente distintas.